# MessageBox OS. Independent

Tags: c++, platform-independent

I want to create an Assert function wich displays a message in a new window without opening the console. The function need to be O.S independent, and not using c++ external libraries if possible.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#ifdef WIN32
#include <windows.h>    // include windows header, for Windows Based Sistems.
#else
// ...
#endif

void Assert (bool cond,const char* file,int line,const char* desc)
{
      if (cond) return;  // No Assertion.
#ifdef WIN32
      // Use MessageBox function to display the information.
      // For Example ...
      std::stringstream st; 
      st << "There Was An Error At Runtime ! \n";
      st << "File: " << file << "\n";
      st << "Line: " << line << "\n";
      st << "Description: " << desc << "\n";
      st << "Do You Want To Continue Running the Application?\n";
      if (MessageBox (NULL,"Unexpected Error", str.str ().c_str (), MB_YESNO) == IDNO)
          exit (-1);
#else
      // Do Something, but in Unix Base Systems.
#endif
}
#define assert(condition,description)  \
            __assert__ (condition,__FILE__,__LINE__,description)
```

Need C++ Code to Output a MessageBox in other O.S

Comment: define other OS - there are so many

Comment: Why don't you actually write the code after the #else for the #ifdef WIN32?  The rest gets to be a lot simpler, we won't have to guess.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ standard does not include GUI operations. You *will* need to make use of external libraries providing GUI services for the platforms you want.

So what you ask for is not possible. Sorry.

Comment: what libraries should I use? GTK, wkWidgets ? simplest library for just print a MessageBox?

Comment: @VictorRuiz Dialog isnt problem, problem is its blocking behavior

Comment: @VictorRuiz Since you only want a message box, use whatever is the default on each system. Bringing up a single message box shouldn't be too difficult. Note that on Mac OS X you will need to write the GUI code in Objective C, not C++. However, your use case seems weird. If your application isn't a GUI one, why would you want to open message boxes? Doesn't make any sense.